# Search for podcast using xmlUrl /Podcast Feed value

Tags: rss, itunes, podcast, opml

I am writing a podcast app in Swift. For podcast search I am using the iTunes api, which works fine. However, I need to do searches using the podcast feed url (xmlUrl) which is either entered manually or extracted from an OPML file, for example "https://feeds.megaphone.fm/slatemoney". This is not a parameter that can be used in the iTunes api. What do people do to search for a podcast using this value as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

TL:DR; The iTunes Search API does not allow searching against the feedUrl. Instead, I recommend querying the iTunes Search API based on the title and episode title of the podcast feed, then comparing against the feed from your user and selecting the best match.

Ideally, you would be able to search the [iTunes Search API][1] using the feedURL field, which is returned when you perform a search on the 'podcast' entity. Example:

```
     "wrapperType": "track",
      "kind": "podcast",
      "collectionId": 1469835145,
      "trackId": 1469835145,
      "artistName": "Jack Johnson",
      "collectionName": "Football Is Anime Podcast",
      "trackName": "Football Is Anime Podcast",
      "collectionCensoredName": "Football Is Anime Podcast",
      "trackCensoredName": "Football Is Anime Podcast",
      "collectionViewUrl": "https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/football-is-anime-podcast/id1469835145?uo=4",
      "feedUrl": "https://feeds.simplecast.com/gbmDbRU_",
...
```

However, feedURL is not an available attribute to search on in the API. The iTunes Search API is limited to the following attributes related to a podcast:

> titleTerm,  languageTerm,  authorTerm,  genreIndex,  artistTerm, 
>   ratingIndex,  keywordsTerm,  descriptionTerm

Even if Apple offered the ability to search by the feed url, I would not trust it for 100% of your searches because many podcasts use various forms of HTTP redirection, which result in a different feedUrl being stored in Apple Podcasts. For example: your user provides http://supercoolpodcast.com/feed , but Apple Podcasts may have https://podcasthost.com/user/supercoolpodcast/feed. Thus, if you searched on the URL it would fail.

You noted you needed to 'do searches using the podcast feed url', but I'm not sure what values you wanted to get from the iTunes Search API. Since you can get most of the podcast metadata in the feedURL that you get from an OPML file or a manually entered feed url, I'll assume you want to get the data that is specific to iTunes: the collectionId, trackId or viewURL.

I recommend querying the iTunes Search API based on the title and episode title of the podcast feed, then comparing against the feed from your user and selecting the best match.

1. Extract the Title and Episode Titles from the podcast feed url that a user provided in your app, which is available in the  tags.
2. Perform a search on the podcast title against the iTunes Search API. Details
   here [1], but here is an [example of the HTTP request](https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=slate%20money&entity=podcast&attribute=titleTerm&).
3. You will probably get multiple results. Each result provides a title you can compare to your user's URL as well as a feedUrl you can query for episode titles and use to compare.

   4. Once you know which result is a match, the original result contains the CollectionId (which is Apple's identifier for that specific podcast), as well as the trackViewUrl (Apple's public URL for that podcast).

   [1] https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-ap

Comment: Thanks for the  answer. I actually am already doing what you recommend, and am trying to optimize it. It is pretty slow to hit the network once to retrieve the title from the podcast feed url and then hit the network  using itunes api to search for the title. This is acceptable when the user is just doing a single search for a podcast using feed url rather than a parameter itunes accepts. But it is  slow when importing perhaps hundreds of feed urls from OPML and having to this for each one. The app needs all of the iTunes metadata to set up the subscription. Just hoping there was a better way.

Comment: Why do you need Apple Podcasts metadata when you already have the feed URL? Do you prefer to use the cached Podcast images that exist on Apple’s servers?

Comment: My experience has been that the xml at the feed url can be really unpredictable. In theory all of the iTunes metadata is available at the feed url, but it can be inconsistently tagged, whereas the itunes metadata is always very clean. But maybe I just need to put more effort into parsing the xml at the feed url- is this how most people do it?

Comment: "The app needs all of the iTunes metadata to set up the subscription." I had thought that only the RSS feed URL was required when subscribing to a podcast?

Comment: "In theory all of the iTunes metadata is available at the feed url, but it can be inconsistently tagged..."
Since you've already retrieved the RSS feed, it would be helpful to use the data that was provided. Perhaps you can add some simple tests on the metadata you receive from the feed, and only then only query into Apple Podcasts when your metadata test(s) breaks.

Comment: Yeah, only the feed url is required to subscribe, but the app also needs description, image url, and other metadata for presentation. But you are right, technically all that is need to subscribe is the feed url.

Comment: Yes, I think it is ultimately more efficient if I parse the rss feed with error checking rather than make two network calls as described above. I was just hoping there was another approach. I'll go ahead and mark your response as the answer, thx.